# Searching for Week Number in Another Workbook and Copy to Original Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to search for "Week #" (Number) within a different Workbook based on the row, once the correct Week has been found I want to copy values from this week and paste it into my Active Workbook. I can't seem to get this to work properly however.

I am able to open up the correct workbook so I know it is not an issue with the WeekFile variable. The WeekNumber variable is equal to a cell containing (example) "Week 39". Assume Range A contains all Week #s in the workbook I'm trying to grab data from.

```
Sub ImportTable()

    Dim count As Integer
    Dim WeekNumber As String

    WeekFile = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J3")
    WeekNumber = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("O7")
    SlideSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Name

    count = 24

    fi$ = "H:\Location\" & WeekFile
    Workbooks.Open fileName:=fi$, ReadOnly:=True
    DataSheet= ActiveWorkbook.Name

    Do While Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & count) <> WeekNumber

        If Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & count) = WeekNumber Then

            Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & count & ":Q" & count).Copy

            Workbooks(SlideSheet).Activate

            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("P7:AE7").PasteSpecial xlValues

            Exit Do

        End If

        count = count + 1

    Loop

    Workbooks(DataSheet).Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: Look into Range.Find method e.g.  Dim found As Range: Set found = Activeworkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A1000").Find(Weeknumber)  I randomly decided 1000 would be the max number of rows to search in. You could find the last populated row in A and use that instead.

Comment: OP, just a note about `Range.Find`. Arguments that you do not provide will default to when it was last used -- so you may need to specify most of its arguments. Alternatively, you could use `Application.match()` and then check for `iserror()`.

Comment: I followed what you said but I keep getting Object required error :/ while using Range Find @QHarr

Comment: Dim weekNumber as long

Answer (score 0):

This is a little easier to follow...

```
    Dim FilePath As String
        FilePath = "H:\Location\"

    Dim WeekFile As String
        WeekFile = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J3").Text

    Dim WeekNumber As String
        WeekNumber = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("O7").Value

        Workbooks.Open Filename:=FilePath & WeekFile & ".xlsx", ReadOnly:=True 
        'use ".xls" extension if needed

    Dim FndwkNbr As Range
        Set FndwkNbr = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns(1).Find(What:=WeekNumber, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)

        FndwkNbr.Offset(, 1).Resize(, 16).Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("P7")
    End Sub
```